# Getting 100% CPU in WebRTC

Tags: webrtc

What steps will reproduce the problem?

1. https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/multiple/
2. Start
3. Call

What is the expected result?
Should initiate call with normal CPU usage, 40-50%.

What do you see instead?
100% CPU usage.

What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?
 -Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1
 -Intel Core 2 Duo , 2.20 GHz
 -2 GB RAM

This issue reproduce with 2 GB RAM only. It is working fine with 4 GB and higher RAM.

[image]

Comment: I am with iOS and same issue with me. has anyone with an idea ?